# Why is python dictionary attribute shared

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python. When I was playing around with the code, I found this.

**Source Code:**

```
dic = {}
mem_dic = {}

def set_op(ind, data):
    global dic, mem_dic
    key, value = data.split()
    dic[key] = int(value)
    mem_dic[ind] = dic
    print(ind, "====", mem_dic)

set_op(0, 'aaa 1')
set_op(1, 'bbb 2')
```

**Expected Output:**

```
0===={0:{'aaa':1}}
1===={0:{'aaa':1},1:{'aaa':1,'bbb':1}}
```

**Actual Output:**

```
0===={0:{'aaa':1,'bbb':1}}
1===={0:{'aaa':1,'bbb':1}}
```

Could anyone please explain the reason for this behavior. And what changes should I incorporate to get the expected output.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @LutzHorn here I am trying to keep a track of the changes in the dictionary during an iteration

Comment: Note that your stated actual output doesn't match the actual output I get when I run it on python2.7; not sure if that's an artifact of changing stuff after the edit or not, but that's not helping your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're not gaining anything by having a global for `dic`. You have one `dic` in your code and you add it to `mem_dic` twice. If you want *two* dicts inside `mem_dic`, don't add the same dict twice.

```
mem_dic = {}

def set_op(ind, data):
    global mem_dic
    key, value = data.split()
    dic = { key: int(value) } # a new dictionary
    mem_dic[ind] = dic
    print(ind, "====", mem_dic)
```

```
>>> set_op(0, 'aaa 1')
0 ==== {0: {'aaa': 1}}
>>> set_op(1, 'bbb 2')
1 ==== {0: {'aaa': 1}, 1: {'bbb': 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new instance of dictionary by changing this line
`mem_dic[ind] = dict(dic)`

```
dic = {}
mem_dic = {}

def set_op(ind, data):
    global dic, mem_dic
    key, value = data.split()
    dic[key] = int(value)
    mem_dic[ind] = dict(dic)
    print(ind, "====", mem_dic)

set_op(0, 'aaa 1')
set_op(1, 'bbb 2')
```

Output

> (1, '====', {0: {'aaa': 1}, 1: {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2}})